# Add multiple login options for user login in a PHP website

Tags: php, authentication, openid

I want to create a login system like Stackoverflow's. I mean the ability to allow the user to login with his/her openid, gmail, facebook, etc. account. How can I achieve this in the easiest and fastest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called HybridAuth.

It is an Open Source login solution for PHP and handles all the auth methods that you mentioned.

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html